# Problem similar to Stieltjes moment problem where $m_n=E[X^n e^{-X}]$

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that we are given the following sequence of moments:
\begin{align}
m_n=E[X^n e^{-X}], \, n=0,1 \dots 
\end{align}
where $X \ge 0$ (non-negative random variable).

Can we show that this sequence of (moments modified by an exponential function) uniquely determines the distribution of $X$.

This problem reminds of both the  Stieltjes moment problem and the uniqueness of Laplace transform (except things are discrete here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $$m_n=E[X^ne^{-X}]=\int_{0}^{\infty}X^ne^{-X}f(x)dx$$We seek to find $f(x)$ therefore if we denote the FT of $f(x)$ by $F(\omega)$ we have$$m_n=\int_{0}^{\infty}X^ne^{-X}f(x)dx=(-1)^nF^{n}(1)$$using Taylor series we have $$F(\omega)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^nm_n}{n!}\omega^n$$so we have $f(x)$

Comment: What does $FFT$ stand for? Some kind of Fourier transform?

Comment: It is the same Fourier transform...

Comment: Thanks. I have a few questions:  1) Can you give a proof of the derivative formula? 2) Do we know that the Taylor series has a positive radius of convergence? 3) Also, should the power series be centered at $\omega=1$?

Comment: Don't have to answer these. I figured it out.

Comment: Why is it not $\sum_0^\infty\frac{m_n}{n!}(\omega-1)^n$?